# Traveling by train from Savannah GA to Charleston SC

Tags: trains, car-rentals, amtrak, georgia-usa, south-carolina

I am looking to travel from Savannah, Georgia to Charleston, South Carolina in February. I have done searching and found the following options:

- Rent a car; probably ~$100 for economy level car, plus some cab fare to and from (it doesn't seem worth it to hold onto a rental car for a few days because most hotels charge a lot for parking in Charleston), plus the liability associated with renting a car
- Take a shuttle bus; $49 per person and only one trip per day in the middle of the day — overpriced (2 people and it's already basically cheaper to rent a car) and doesn't run when I need to leave
- Take the train (Amtrak) seeing $22 tickets the cheapest (plus cab to and from stations on either end); morning departure works nicely for my itinerary and trip seems to last about as long as driving.
- Greyhound bus, apparently $24 / person and 2 h long based on comment below. Not quite as comfortable as a train.

I have seen a lot of people online suggesting renting or the shuttle bus, but surprisingly little recommending the train. Is there a specific reason? Is it unreliable, uncomfortable, or inconvenient? In general I haven't really ever taken an Amtrak train, but I was surprised to see the tickets were so cheap.

My goal is to minimize cost without adding too much time or inconvenience/discomfort. Seems pointless to rent a car just for a couple hours.

Comment: You've written "North Carolina" in the question, but used the [tag:south-carolina] tag.  Which is it?  The answer will be rather different.

Comment: Sorry, should be South Carolina. Thanks. Updated. AFAIK there is no Charleston NC — boy that would be confusing for people.

Comment: Good point. Another viable option, thanks. Although all things equal trains are certainly more comfortable.

Comment: There is in fact a [Charleston, NC](https://goo.gl/maps/KytKRHJPcjx) in the Google Maps database, but if you search for it on Google Maps you get North Charleston, SC.  To get a map of Charleston, NC, I had to pick it from the search-as-you-type list.  It is not near any passenger rail service, however, and I can't find any evidence of an actual place called Charleston in the indicated area.

Comment: Ah, ok… yea was trying to find one but I was getting North Charleston. Not surprising as there are [dozens of Charlestons in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charleston).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drive between the two cities is only two hours, and as with the U.S. in general, gasoline is extremely inexpensive compared to most of the world, and the road network is extensive and reasonably well-maintained, so the vast majority of people with access to a car will drive this route. I agree with you, however, that once you arrive, it will be a hassle to drive around the crowded historic core and to find parking. If traveling solo, **I would certainly consider Amtrak** or one of the bus options.

Most people would find any Amtrak experience far more comfortable than flying economy or taking a long-distance bus. There is no security screening. The seats are wider, with considerably greater legroom, with an electrical outlet for every seat. The restrooms aboard are larger. There is almost never a fight over luggage storage. The train is large enough that you can get up to walk around to stretch your legs, and there will often be a cafe car or lounge where you can sit at a booth to socialize.

**Reliability** can be a concern. According to the [Amtrak Status Maps Archive Database](https://juckins.net/amtrak_status/archive/html/history.php?train_num=90&station=sav&date_start=12%2F23%2F2018&date_end=01%2F22%2F2019&df1=1&df2=1&df3=1&df4=1&df5=1&df6=1&df7=1&sort=schDp&sort_dir=DESC&co=gt&limit_mins=&dfon=1) (ASMAD), the morning train (the Palmetto, #90), has left SAV on time almost every day for the last month, and arrived at CHS with a median delay of only 3 minutes over the same time period. The evening train (the Silver Meteor #98) has a rather worse record, with a median departure delay of 38 minutes and a median arrival delay of 51 minutes; 20 of 30 were more than half an hour late. Again, however, I'd much rather spend an extra hour on Amtrak than an extra fifteen minutes on, say, Spirit Airlines.

While Amtrak in some cities is ideal for traveling downtown to downtown, **convenience** is not a strong selling point here. The stations are about four miles and nine miles from Savannah and Charleston's respective city markets. This may be why people recommend the Basin Bus for tourists, since it goes from tourist district to tourist district directly. Savannah's Greyhound terminal is also located in the downtown area, although Charleston's is still a taxi ride away.

---

Amtrak will rank among the preferred transportation options within the [Northeast](https://www.amtrak.com/northeast-train-routes), and especially between the major cities along the [Northeast Corridor](https://nec.amtrak.com/). Other than a handful of intra-state corridor routes, it does not come close to that mark anywhere else in the country. This is not necessarily because most people have bad experiences with Amtrak, but because most people do not have any experience with Amtrak at all. Intercity rail is not practical for most people for most travel at most times in most of the United States. Many Americans are unaware service is available in a particular locale, or forget that Amtrak even exists.

There is extensive commentary on the historical and economic reasons for the decline of passenger railroads in the U.S.—too much to get into on TSE—and the matter is extremely fraught politically. For now, there is enough political will to subsidize Amtrak enough to keep it going, but not enough either fund it to the point where it could thrive or to cut it off entirely. I leave it to you to research the root causes on your own.

In ***practical***, retail-level terms, Amtrak is not a viable for many travelers in many parts of the country for reasons that include one or more of the following:

- *Frequency*. Many cities are served by only one or two trains in each direction per day. There is no service at all even to some large cities, like Columbus, Ohio or Nashville, Tennessee, each with a metro area population of around 2 million people. Even between Washington, D.C. and Chicago, there is only a single daily direct train in each direction, while United Airlines currently sells no fewer than *22* nonstops.
- *Schedule*. As a corollary to the limited frequency, departure and arrival times will be impractical for many. That Washington-Pittsburgh service (the Capitol Limited) departs Washington at 16:05 and arrives in Pittsburgh at 23:48. The return departs at 05:20 and arrives 13:05. That makes it impractical for a business trip or even a weekend family visit to Pittsburgh considering I can drive there in four hours or fly there in about one hour. Why doesn't Amtrak schedule more trips? In many cases, they would, to meet demand, but Amtrak does not have any extra trains, nor the capital to purchase them, and many rail lines are being run at capacity anyway
- *Reliability*. Every mode of transportation can see delays and irregular operations, of course, but it is a much bigger ordeal to reroute a train to avoid, say, flooded track, than it is to reroute a bus or a plane. Although Amtrak trains have priority over freight trains, they still have to share the tracks, and you can get stuck behind a freight train on many services. In the Northeast in particular, you have issues with [aging infrastructure](https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2017-penn-station-summer-construction-creates-commuting-hell/)
- *Speed*. I can drive from Washington to Pittsburgh in four hours; the most direct Amtrak service takes more than seven and a half. Of course, on other routes, you may save a lot of time avoiding traffic, besides the cost of parking and fuel and of course the rental itself, but there is a tipping point for each city pair. Add to this that many train stations are located outside city centers, so may not be any more convenient than a small airport.
- *Cost*. Coach seats on long-distance trains can be relatively inexpensive, as you've found. On other routes, it's impractical compared to driving or flying. It's quite expensive along the NEC, but even on inexpensive routes, the fares add up, especially for groups. Two people can drive from Los Angeles to San Diego in about three hours for under $10 per person in gasoline. They could instead take Amtrak's Pacific Surfliner, which is a generally fantastic ride, and take roughly the same amount of time, but it would cost $35 each.
- *Competition*. The domestic air and road network in the U.S. is well-developed. September 11 was an outsized economic shock in part because at the time, half of all air travel in the world (measured by revenue passenger kilometers) was within the United States. Consider that nowadays, from Washington to New York, you can take a bus that takes about 4½ hours and costs $19; you can take Amtrak, which takes 3½ hours and costs $80; or you can take the Delta Shuttle, which costs $100 and takes about one hour. Mind you, this is one of the routes where it makes the *most* sense to take Amtrak in terms of other practicalities, but it remains that if you want to save money, you'd take the bus, and if you want to save time, you'd fly.
- *Unfamiliarity*. You don't recommend what you can't vouch for, and at this point in our history, a distinct minority of people have taken Amtrak or its predecessors. That, again, is a trend that started decades ago and accelerated greatly with jet aircraft and interstate highways. When I moved to the East Coast and started taking the train, at least a few of my West Coast friends said it was "weird."

Comment: Note, the Basin Bus seems to leave from across the water in Savannah… so you have to take a ferry to get there? Seems pretty annoying. Plus they want $50 for a 2 hour ride, which, if you're going with a group can be a lot more than a car rental.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your description, it seems Amtrak would be the most practical option.  A car would be faster, but all things considered, Amtrak is also an option.

The Amtrak stations are not city-center so Uber, cab or local bus would be required.

I have travelled on various inter-city Amtrak services and I would describe it as 'perfectly serviceable'.  The seats are fine for 2-3 hours but describing them as 'sleeper' is a huge exaggeration.

Amtrak is either on-time...or it's not.  That segment is right in the middle of the long-haul service so some delay wouldn't be surprising.

Comment: The train in question has sleeping cars, but of course for this short leg it would be ridiculous to pay for one.

Comment: I have travelled to Charleston by train, and yes it is not city center (feels like the middle of an industrial area), but the taxi drivers know to show up when the train arrives - and my train was late getting in

Comment: @PeterM so would you recommend traveling to Charleston by train?

Comment: @shim I wouldn' t say no